# To Replace character values with numbers

Tags: r

In my data set there is a column named "Faculty" that includes name of faculties. I want to replace the names with corresponding codes (numbers). For example, the following code produces a small sample.

```
Faculty<-data.frame(Faculty=c("Forestry","Advanced Technology", "erontology","Design and Architecture","Veterinary Medicine"))
```

In R, I want to replace all names with codes throughout the data frame. lets say:

```
Faculty.code<-data.frame(Faculty=c("23","34", "15","7","11"))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just to remind that there are thousands of rows. Thanks.

Comment: It's already a factor, which is stored as integers, so you can just use `as.integer(Faculty$Faculty)`. If you care what the numbers are, it's a bit more work.

Comment: A look-up table is probably quicker if there are many rows, though 'thousands' is probably going to make no difference - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456968/how-do-i-map-a-vector-of-values-to-another-vector-with-my-own-custom-map-in-r?lq=1

Comment: @alistaire yes we care bout numbers as codes are specified.

Comment: ...then you need to show how the codes are stored and linked to the respective names.

Comment: @alistaire codes are a separate list in doc format, they are not in the dataset. There are 26 faculty names in dataset which must be replaces with 26 codes.

Comment: Well, have you imported them into R? Are they in a data.frame? A list? A named integer of character vector? Are you just going to type them all in? 26 levels is not that many; akrun's solution should work, if you substitute concise vectors for `levels` and `labels`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `factor`

```
  factor(Faculty$Faculty, levels= unique(Faculty$Faculty), 
         labels=c("23","34", "15","7","11"))
```

Comment: Thanks but codes must be replaced with faculties throughout the dataset which is about 10 thousand rows, how do I do that? a friend suggested look-up table but I have not look into it.

Comment: @Sahara  If there are 1000s of levels, making a look up table could also takes some time.

Comment: Can you think of a more efficient solution?

Comment: @Sahara It all depends on whether you have any pattern or not.  If the new labels have no direct connection whatsoever with the previous one, making the lookup table is the option.