# Why is `[` subsetting with NA so slow?

Tags: r

What is the prefered way to do this?

Using `[` and a named key vector to recode another vector is, I thought until recently, a robust and preferred "R" idiom for performing a common task. Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Details about the task: I have a character vector that has a length of approx 1e6, each element being one char long strings. I want to convert this vector to be numeric, such that ("B", "H", "K", "M"), which are abbreviations for an order of magnitude (H = hundred, M = million, etc.) become numeric (H = 100, M = 1e6, etc.) Any other chars not in the set of 4, or `NA`s, are to become `1`.

After much trial and error I've tracked it down to the fact that `NA`s in the subsetting vector substantially slow down the operation. I find this inherently confusing, because it seems to me that subsetting with `NA` should, if anything, be faster, because it doesnt even need to search through the subsetted vector, it only needs to return an NA.

```
y <-  c("B", "H", "K", "M")
without_NA <- sample(rep_len(y, 1e6))
with_NA <- sample(rep_len(c(y, NA), 1e6))

convert_exponent_char_to_numeric <- function(exponent) {
  exponent_key <- 10^c(2, 3*1:3)
  names(exponent_key) <- c("H", "K", "M", "B")

  out <- exponent_key[exponent]
  out[is.na(out)] <- 1
  out
}

system.time(convert_exponent_char_to_numeric(without_NA))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.136   0.011   0.147 
system.time(convert_exponent_char_to_numeric(with_NA))
   user  system elapsed 
303.342   0.691 304.237
```

Comment: Using a `data.frame` lookup table will speed things up too, as per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18457055/496803

Comment: Use `match`: `out <- exponent_key[match(exponent,c("H", "K", "M", "B")
)]`.

Comment: @nicola - True - I suspect the speed of the lookup table from the answer I linked is due to using `match`.

Comment: Thank you both. `match()` did the trick, and saves me a step by having a `nomatch` argument. I ended up using a data.frame to keep things organized, because using `names` didn't make sense anymore with this new approach. I still don't understand why `[` is so slow with `NA`s in the vector (to the point of being unusable). This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround to keep it from being slowed down by the extra code being invoked with `NA` detection:

```
y          <-  c("B", "H", "K", "M")
without_NA <- sample(rep_len(y, 1e6))
with_NA    <- sample(rep_len(c(y, NA), 1e6))
with_NA[is.na(with_NA)] <- "NA"

convert_exponent_char_to_numeric <- function(exponent) {
  exponent_key <- 10^c(2, 3*1:3)
  exponent_key <- c(exponent_key, 1)
  names(exponent_key) <- c("H", "K", "M", "B", "NA")

  out <- exponent_key[exponent]
  out
}

system.time(convert_exponent_char_to_numeric(without_NA))
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed 
>    0.03    0.01    0.04
> ```

```
system.time(convert_exponent_char_to_numeric(with_NA))
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed 
>    0.04    0.01    0.05
> ```

Now they are both well under 1 second. The 1/100th of a second extra time taken with the `with_NA` version is just because there are 5 levels to match on instead of 4.