# Change the specific values of columns when there are so many columns using R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I simplified the data `df` for demonstration purpose.

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,3,4,5,6,7),title_1=c("H","M","","M","L","L","H")
               ,title_2=c("M","M","","L","L","L","H")
               ,title_3=c("H","H","M","L","","M","M"))
```

what I want to do is change the values.If the value is null `""`, then I want to change it to `0`.
If the value is `H`, I want to change it to `3`. If the value is `M`, I want to change it to `2`.
If the value is `L`, I want to change it to `1`. The reason why I stuck here is because in my actual data, there are so many columns named as `titel_1, title_2,title_3, ... ,title_100`.So, I cannot type every columns to do this . So I need the code that is applicable to the data that has many columns.

Comment: I reckon using a lookup table will be straight-forward and flexible for this sort of thing, as per this old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456968/how-do-i-map-a-vector-of-values-to-another-vector-with-my-own-custom-map-in-r/18457055 - e.g. `lkup <- data.frame(old = c("", "H", "M", "L"), new=c(0,3,2,1)); df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], \(x) lkup$new[match(x,lkup$old)] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace(., . ==  "", 0)),
         across(everything(), ~replace(., . ==  "H", 3)),
         across(everything(), ~replace(., . ==  "M", 2)),
         across(everything(), ~replace(., . ==  "L", 1))
         )

  id title_1 title_2 title_3
1  1       3       2       3
2  1       2       2       3
3  3       0       0       2
4  4       2       1       1
5  5       1       1       0
6  6       1       1       2
7  7       3       3       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `dplyr::recode`

```r
df %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with("title"), recode, "L" = 1, "M" = 2, "H" = 3, .default = 0))
#  id title_1 title_2 title_3
#1  1       3       2       3
#2  1       2       2       3
#3  3       0       0       2
#4  4       2       1       1
#5  5       1       1       0
#6  6       1       1       2
#7  7       3       3       2
```